# Custom real-time drawing in Qt5 and Qt Quick 2

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

I have been looking far and wide to find out how, if it’s possible, you can fill a particular area in a QML screen with an OpenGL context and do custom OpenGL only in that context. I’ve seen plenty of demos where the QML components like buttons, etc lay on top or below a screen-wide OpenGL context (as is typically required by games), but I’d like to be able to situate several distinct OpenGL contexts within QML and have the QML file define how large they are, where they are positioned, etc.

Now, since Qt 5 is all OpenGL under the hood, it makes me wonder if using a Canvas element with custom drawing via javascript could result in similar rendering performance as custom OpenGL? This would be a meaningful alternative but it’s not clear to me how the javascript drawing is handled via runtime compared to custom OpenGL drawing.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-canvas.html I guess you read about renderTarget and renderStrategy?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld my understanding is that only specifies how Qt will handle the drawing commands under the hood, but that the API you can use in the Canvas is not OpenGL, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it that you want to draw? `QQuickPaintedItem` may be the simplest way to go about it. When you're using `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` as the target, the painter will use OpenGL to paint the texture. It might be easier than writing your own OpenGL code if all you're doing is 2D.